# Call same method multiple times on different parts of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a method which can only work with an array of maximum 100 objets.

However I have an array with more than 100 objects, how could I call this method multiple times so it will work for arrays which have more than 100 objets?

Let's say I have an array of 264 objects.

I could call the method 3 times like so:

```
[self doSomething:[arrayWithMoreThan100Objects subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 100)];
[self doSomething:[arrayWithMoreThan100Objects subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(100, 100)];
[self doSomething:[arrayWithMoreThan100Objects subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(200, 64)];
```

This works fine, however I don't always know the size of the array the method needs to process so calling this manually wont work.

How could I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean something like `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
NSInteger increment = 100;
for (NSInteger start = 0; start < arrayWithMoreThan100Objects.count; start += increment) {
    NSInteger length = MIN(increment, arrayWithMoreThan100Objects.count - start);
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, length);
    [self doSomething:[arrayWithMoreThan100Objects subarrayWithRange:range];
}
```

The value of `length` is set to either 100 or a smaller value if there are less than 100 objects left in the array.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, just what I needed! Can you add some explanation to the code though, so I can understand. I don' want to copy and paste only. Thanks!

Comment: What part do you need clarified? It's a simple loop.

Comment: I could not understand how does it know not to add 100 more to the range if there are not 100 objects left, but than I realised that that is exactly what MIN does. Thanks a ton! Very elegant solution.

Comment: It's a simple loop that increments by a hundred, with the start as the first parameter passed in `NSMakeRange`, while the *64* in your `NSMakeRange(200, 64)` represented by the minimum value of your total array in `arrayWithMoreThan100Objects` and the iteration variable. Because at first iteration, the substraction of array length may exceed the increment that you want (100), we take the minimum value of them, which is 100, or 64 at the last iteration.

------------- seems my comment was unnecessary